# Child view constraints to parent view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, constraints

I added 4 constrains to a child view of my main view of my initial view controller. Top space and leading space with 0 as the constant and equal width and height with the parent view. No matter what I do the child view won't be at coordinates 0,0 , it always is at coordinates 16,20, even if the constants are 0.

Comment: Did you add these constraints in the storyboard? You are probably making the constraints to the view's margins instead of its edges (there's a checkbox in the pin popup that's selected by default, that you should deselect).

Comment: Yes, I added them in storyboard. What checkbox? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your top and leading constraints. Then, create them again. Only this time, when you're creating them, uncheck "constrain to margins" checkbox.

This is the checkbox I'm talking about:

[image]